# Type with default value

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to create type which will be declared with default value.
Instead writing the same declaration:

```
class Test{
a: string = '';
b: string = '';
c: string = '';
...
}
```

[BTW. it look's bad]
to write only type

```
class Test{
a: type_with_default_value;
b: type_with_default_value;
c: type_with_default_value;
}
```

Much prettier

Answer (score 1):

You can define a constant with the default value, and let inference take care of the type

```
const noString = '' // you can specify the type of the const 
class Test {
  a = noString;
  b = noString;
  c = noString;

}
```

In Typescript types and values share differ universes. There is no way for a type annotation to also assign a default value to the field.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to create type which will be **declared** with default value

No, it is not possible because of this: you declare o variable, not define it, therefore you are not actually setting any value, which you have to do somewhere.

There are languages, which do default initialization for some cases ([C++ is an example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization)) but TypeScript can only default-initialize to `undefined` [when `--strictPropertyInitialization` flag is not used](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/20075)

Therefore, you are left with the following options:

1. What you are doing now: `a: string = '';`
2. Initialization in the constructor: `constructor() { this.a = ''; }`